# before vs in the past

Tags: present-perfect

Are "before" and "in the past" interchangeable in these sentences?

1. They've been to Italy before.
2. They've been to Italy in the past.
3. I've eaten sushi several times before.
4. I've eaten sushi several times in the past.
5. She's lived in London before.
6. She's lived in London in the past.

Comment: I would suggest that _in the past_ implies that the previous experience was some time ago.

Comment: Do you mean both work, but aren't interchangeable? Can I say that "in the past" implies long ago, while "before" could mean long ago, but could also mean recently?

Comment: Both mean 'on one or more occasions before the present time', but I consider that _in the past_ is more likely to be used if those occasions were not recent.